# Row Range Increases Monthly - (INDIRECT) to dynamically increase in Formulas?

Tags: worksheet-function

```
COUNTIFS($C$25:$C$271,">="&$O5,$C$25:$C$271,"<="&$P5)
```

If rows increase (271 this month, increasing every month), how can I dynamically increase that row reference using `indirect`, retaining the absolute reference?

Right now, I am entering that row reference manually as the range increases monthly.

Comment: what exactly you've tried already? how your data looks like?

Comment: Why bother, COUNTIFS has no detriment to full column use: `COUNTIFS($C:$C,">="&$O5,$C:$C,"<="&$P5)`